# Filter data according to Date in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a database with two tables .

First Table  `Card : CardId, Description`. - Keeps record of all the card available
Second Table `RegistartionDt : RegistartionDtId, RegisteredDateTime` , `CardId`. keep data of the time and data a particular card is used.

I want to make a search function that will search for the cards by the date . For example the user will chose from the drop-down menu the date. Start date and end date and search for the cards being used in that range.

In my home controller I have an actionresult that takes the start date and the end date.

And I am stuck here. Can you please guide me. What to do next ? How to connect the tables? 
What ABOUT the view.

I am new in asp.net and mvc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Add HttpGet **I am useing my variables you can put yours**

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult ShowTask()
    {
        ShowTask model = new ShowTask();

        var TaskData = (from d in edc.TaskTBs
                        join d1 in edc.TaskToUserTBs on d.TaskID equals d1.TaskID
                        where d.IsActive == true && d1.RegistrationId == Convert.ToInt32(Session["RegistrationId"])
                        select new
                        {
                            d.ProjectTB.ProjectName,
                            d1.RegistrationId,
                            d.TaskID,
                            d.DBName,
                            d.Description,
                            d.FromDate,
                            d.ToDate,
                            d.ProjectID,
                            d1.RegistrationTB.Name,
                            d1.RegistrationTB.Email
                        }).OrderByDescending(x => x.TaskID).ToList();
        if (TaskData != null)
        {
            if (model.FromSearchDate.ToString() != "" && model.FromSearchDate.ToString() != "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM")
            {
                TaskData = TaskData.Where(x => x.FromDate.Contains(model.FromSearchDate.ToString())).ToList();
            }
            if (model.FromSearchDate.ToString() != "" && model.ToSearchDate.ToString() != "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM")
            {
                TaskData = TaskData.Where(x => x.ToDate.Contains(model.ToSearchDate.ToString())).ToList();
            }
            model.Tasklist = TaskData;
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

You can recall this method after postback.

Comment: Let me try this . Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The SQL Query would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(CARDID)
FROM CARD a
INNER JOIN
REGISTRATIONDT b
ON a.CARDID = b.CARDID
WHERE REGISTEREDDATETIME BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
```

Call the database with that query and insert start and end dates. You will probably want to use named parameters for inserting user provided values(start/end date) so you have a layer of protection from SQL Injection.

Your SqlCommand commandText property is your SQL statement, then you can call sqlCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", startDate) etc. for other parameters.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to link your databases, you can use LINQ like this:

```
var innerJoinQuery =
    from card in Card 
    join regIdDt in RegistartionDton card.CardId equals RegistartionDt.CardId
    where regIdDt.RegisteredDateTime  >= _startDate && regIdDt.RegisteredDateTime <= _endDate
    select new { };
```

You join the two tables together using their common field and then you add a where parameter that searches for the dates between the given start- & endDate, and this should return the data you need. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you I really needed this .